# How to set a specific date on a count up timer

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I am trying to make a count up timer from a specific date. I used this (http://tutorialzine.com/2012/09/count-up-jquery/) tutorial to do it but i don't know where to put in:

$('#countdown').countup({
    start: new Date(2012, 10, 27, 15, 58, 21) //year, month, day, hour, min, sec
});

as it says in the description.

The beginning of the code looks like this:

```
(function($){

    // Number of seconds in every time division
    var days    = 24*60*60,
        hours   = 60*60,
        minutes = 60;

    // Creating the plugin
    $.fn.countup = function(prop){

        var options = $.extend({
            callback    : function(){},
            start       : new Date()
        },prop);    

        var passed = 0, d, h, m, s, 
            positions;

        // Initialize the plugin
        init(this, options);

        positions = this.find('.position');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the plugin using

```
$('#countdown').countup({ start: new Date(2012, 10, 27, 15, 58, 21) //year, month, day, hour, min, sec });
```

Where your html will have an element with id="countdown"

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

now you can put it virtually anywhere in your JS. Lets say you want to call this plugin when window loads, the JS file you include could have something like:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $('#countdown').countup({ start: new Date(2012, 10, 27, 15, 58, 21)});
})
```

Breaking down whats happening:

```
$("#countdown").countup()//calls a jQuery function obviously
```

As an argument you are passing an object 
    {star:new Date()}

Here's a little detail of the accepted format Javascript Date() method would accept: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Now once you call the .countup() function, notice the $.extend() part, which basically copies second object on to the first, i.e. if you pass on

```
{start:new Date("2015-11-10")}
```

this overrides the default key start in the function definition. If you do not pass on this as an argument it just falls back to new Date() which essentially is current date-time.

Comment: I've up voted your answer and also posted another example as a supplement to your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete working example. Run the snippet to see it work.

See @Anubhab's answer (up voted) for the details of how it works. Additionally, make sure your page includes all the required CSS and Javascript files required to make it work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/09/count-up-jquery/assets/countup/jquery.countup.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/09/count-up-jquery/assets/countup/jquery.countup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="countdown"></div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      // jQuery ready - create counter
      $('#countdown').countup({
        start: new Date(2016, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! But the counter is not correct according to the date that is set, how do i fix that?

Comment: @RikardAbrahamsson - It appears that the plug-in has a maximum of 99 days.  You would need to modify the plug-in code to show more digits or use a start date that is less than 100 days. I have changed the start date in the example to 1-1-2016 and this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

For ReactJs people,

You can use this shared component

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';


const CountUpTimer = ({ startDate }) => {
    const currentTime = moment().unix()
    const jobStart = moment(startDate).unix()

    const startTime = currentTime - jobStart
    const [timer, setTimer] = React.useState(Number(startTime) || 0);

    let hour = React.useRef(0);
    let minute = React.useRef(0);
    let upSecond = React.useRef(0);

    const countTimer = React.useCallback(() => {
        setTimer(timer + 1);
        hour.current = Math.floor(timer / 3600);
        minute.current = Math.floor((timer - hour.current * 3600) / 60);
        upSecond.current = timer - (hour.current * 3600 + minute.current * 60);

    }, [timer]);


    React.useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            countTimer()
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [timer, countTimer]);

    return <div>{hour.current}:{minute.current}:{upSecond.current}</div>;
};

export default CountUpTimer;
```

At the point of display, you can add the second passed to the start time and format using moment.